# How to quick match an entry with the beginning of a long string?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql

I have a table `articles` (:Rails Model but I think the issue is more SQL related) which have a column name `permalink`. To instance, some of my permalinks :

```
title-of-article
great-article
great-article-about-obama
obama-stuff-about-him
```

I want to match a request like `great-article-about-obama-random-stuff` to `great-article-about-obama`. Is it possible to do it, avoiding killing performance ?

Thanks to all,

ps : We use Rails 3 and Postgresql (or Sqlite not decided yet for production)

EDIT

We can do something like this, but the main downside is we have to fetched every single permalinks from the table articles :

```
permalinks = ['title-of-article','great-article','great-article-about-obama','obama-stuff-about-him']
string_to_match = 'great-article-about-obama-random-stuf'
result = permalinks.inject('') do |matched,permalink|
  matched = (string_to_match.include? permalink and permalink.size > matched.size) ? permalink : matched
end
result => 'great-article-about-obama'
```

I'll love to find a way to do it directly in `SQL` for obvious performance reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless using a text-search base technology (w/ postgres : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html + http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/10/17/full-text-search-on-heroku/ or solr, indexTank) you can do it with :

```
request = "chien-qui-aboie"
article = nil

while !article do
  article = Article.where("permalink like ?", request+"%").select(:id).first
  request.gsub!(/-[^-]*$/) unless article
end
```

This will first look for *chien-qui-aboie%*, then *chien-qui%*, then *chien%*.

This will also match "chien_qui_mange" if there is an article "chien_qui_mange" but no one about "chien qui aboie"

That's not optimal because of the number of requests, but that's not that heavy if it's just a look up, and not the normal way of accessing a record.

Comment: Yeah, but you've to make assumption about where to cut the string to pass to the sql `LIKE`. For example, how you guess where to cut `great-article-about-obama-other-things` ?

Comment: it's pretty the same. Another example, `title-of-article-blabla-blibli-bloblo`. You cannot guess that you have `title-of-article` in a side and `-blabla-blibli-bloblo` on the other, you have to make a request to the database. The issue is what will be this request ?

Comment: I can't really understand :) Would you give an example like "given a parameter 'blibli' I want to access to the article xxx", or what's actually going on your website ?

Comment: Humm, I hardly see how to explain this thing in another way :) From database side, you have a table with animals (:example) `chien-qui, chatons-pas, chat-de-paris, cheval`. I have a string like `chiens-qui-courrent`, I want this string to match `chien-qui` in the database.

Comment: Other way you'll have to look into other technologies like Solr, indexTank, and text-search dictonnary-based databases

Comment: Yeah, it was something I was thinking of. The only issue here is the performance. A lot of `SQL LIKE` is painfull.

Comment: And, if you're using postgres8.3 + take a look at : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html

Comment: take a look at : http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/10/17/full-text-search-on-heroku/

Comment: Look to my edit, I will run a benchmark to see which of your or mine will perform the best. Love to find a more elegant solution.